# How do I group and sum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table that includes `:firm_id, :carrier_id, :month, :amount` columns.  I am trying to group my `:carrier_id` and `:month` and then sum the `:amount`.  For example:

current database table:

```
firm_id | carrier_id | month | amount
 1      |      1     |  jan  |  $100
 2      |      1     |  jan  |  $100
 3      |      2     |  jan  |  $100
 1      |      1     |  feb  |  $100
 2      |      2     |  feb  |  $100
 3      |      2     |  feb  |  $100
```

the table view I would like to create:

```
carrier_id | month | amount
     1     |  jan  |  $200
     2     |  jan  |  $100
     1     |  feb  |  $100
     2     |  feb  |  $200
```

I have already tried this in my model (based on some research) with no success

```
Production.select(:carrier_id, :month, :amount, "SUM(amount)").group(:carrier_id, :month)
```

Can someone lend some help with this or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.. I would invite suggestion on how I might improve this..thanks

**my model:**

```
Production.find(
    :all,
    select: "month, carrier_id, amount, SUM(amount) as sum_amount",
    group: :carrier_id
    )
```